# Algorithm to find $n$ player nash equilibrium

Tags: ds.algorithms, gt.game-theory

This is the question asked [10 years before](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1994/algorithms-for-nash-equilibrium-computation?newreg=cd326e0785eb43068fb58936056f7b50).

Most of the algorithm and software mentioned are out of date. I am wondering is there new approchs for this problem in the last 10 years?

The game dealing with is $n$ player, finite actions, general sum.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of computing Nash equilibria in general games is PPAD complete (which is believed to be hard), even for 2-player games. This was proven for 3-player games by Daskalakis et al. for 3-player games [in this paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/costis/journal_ver10.pdf) and extended to 2-player games by Chen et al. [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.1678.pdf). See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPAD_(complexity)) on the PPAD class for more details.

There are nonetheless many approaches to finding equilibria if you have further game structure, from convexity of the payoff functions to potential and zero-sum games.

Having said that, even finding local min-max equilibria in two-player zero-sum games with nonconvex-nonconcave objectives was recently proven to be PPAD complete (as hard as finding Nash equilibria in general games) by Daskalakis et al., see [this video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNsrHLpjkvo&t=4739s).